# Как получить значение поля ввода

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/
```

Я хочу получить значение поля `email`. Допустим я введу в поле ввода строку - 1@mail.ru. Как мне его получить средствами js? Какими только методами не пробовал - выдает `undefined`.

Я пробовал и через xpath, и через Id - выдает undefined

Answer (score 2):

Я сам новичок в этом деле, такой вариант подходит:

```js
my = () => {
  let n = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  console.log(n);
};
```

```html
<input type="email" onchange="my()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть на элемент для ввода логина на этом сайте через инструменты разработчика, то можно найти у него `id`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самый простой способ получения данных из элемента, обратиться к нему по `id`

```
console.log(document.getElementById('i0116').value);
```