# Как вывести значение поля ввода?

Tags: javascript, html, input

[Как получить значение поля ввода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811887/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

---

У меня подобный вопрос, но предложенные варианты решения не помогают совсем.

```
function click() {
    let x =  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    console.log(x);
}

    <input type="text" id="inp" onchange='click()'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('inp');

// Если хотите, чтоб при каждом изменение значения формы выполнялось действие
input.addEventListener('input', function(event){ console.log(this.value) });
 
// если нужно единоразово получить значение где-то
console.log(input.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" onchange=''>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
input.oninput = e => console.log(e.target.value);
// или
// input.oninput = function() { console.log(this.value) };
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```